# Where is <option> tag in websharper?

Tags: f#, websharper

I see [here](https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper/blob/5c884e97fd3dba1102c10a85b171f672d0b3f637/src/htmllib/tags.csv#L85) that the tag for `<option>` is marked as "colliding" which I assume has something to do with why when I have

`open WebSharper.Html.Client`

and am looking through the list of tags at `WebSharper.Html.Client.Tags.` I do not see `Option` as an available tag.  Is there any other way I can create an `<option>` element?  I am familiar with Formlets and Piglets, but for this specific situation those will not not work.

Comment: You could use `NewTag "option"`